# How to do remote debugging using gdbserver?

Tags: linux, gdb, arm, gdbserver

I have one program that is getting segment fault. I need to debug that remotely.
For that I am doing following:

On target board:

```
#gdbserver :2345 program
```

On host x86 machine:

```
$ arm-linux-gdb -q program
(gdb) target remote 192.168.150.104:2345
```

But after running above command I am getting number of errors:

```
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/usr/local/lib/QtTouchScreen/lib/libQtTest.so.4: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/usr/local/lib/QtTouchScreen/lib/libQtXml.so.4: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/usr/local/lib/QtTouchScreen/lib/libQtGui.so.4: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/usr/local/lib/QtTouchScreen/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/usr/local/lib/QtTouchScreen/lib/libQtCore.so.4: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/lib/libpthread.so.0: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/lib/libm.so.0: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory.
```

I tried to set path of these libs on host where they are placed using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but still no luck.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Yuvi

Comment: Do you have necessary Qt libs install for running your program for ARM arch?

Comment: You need to set `sysroot`.

Comment: @rakib Where host or target ?

Comment: On system, where (/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory etc.) messages are shown.

Comment: @devnull your suggestion worked. Answer the same, so that I can accept that.

Comment: Also: *solib-search-path*.  The *sysroot* will not find the Qt libraries if they are in different directories.  See [GDB docs](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `sysroot`.  If you have the libraries available locally, you can say:

```
set sysroot host-pathname
```